# Hide sensitive data in an association relationship in java @JsonProperty

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jackson

How can I hide some sensitive data on this example. I'm testing APIs in rest client (Postman), when I call Api List of Bills, I want to hide some data. In BillsDto I want to hide username, password and user age fields. Is it possible to do this in my BillsDto class (not in UserDto). I know I can hide some fields using @JsonProperty but how to do it for some fields belonging to another class?

```
***BillsDto***

public class BillsDto {

private String numberBills;
private double amount;
private Date deadlinePayment
private UserDto user;  // try to hide username, password, age from BillsDto

}
```

```
***UserDto***

public class UserDto {

private String number_id;
private String username;
private String password;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String age;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know I can hide some fields using `@JsonProperty` but how to do it for some fields belonging to another class?

The fact that you're using `UserDto` as a nested object somewhere, doesn't change the serialization policy that you can express through data binding annotations in the `UserDto`.

If you can change `UserDto`, apply `@JsonProperty` with it's property `access` set to `JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY` on the fields want to hide during serialization.

```
public class UserDto {
    private String number_id;
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private String username;
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private String age;
}
```

If for some reason, you want to achieve this by editing `BillsDto` only, then you can implement a custom serializer for `UserDto` and apply it by making use of the `@JsonSerialize`. But to ensure that you're not disclosing the sensitive data somewhere, it would be better to apply this policy in one place - in the `UserDto`, because you or one of your colleagues might simply forget to `@JsonSerialize` in some of the classes which uses `UserDto`.